# Creating Custom QR Code (Snapchat, Messenger)

Tags: customization, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

A Chinese social app "Wechat" created a custom qr Code and that idea brought to west by "snapchat" and now Facebook is also utilizing it. I Know there are guidelines to create a QR Code and these guys customized it based on there needs. I was looking for help in the same path to create my own Customized QR Codes.

Solution Required: Snapchat, Messenger style barcode/qrcode reader and writer.

Please share your thoughts or if there is any opensource script.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Could you highlight what you have already tried? In general, you could start looking into how a QR code is defined. There are several software packages out there (openCV for example) that can read QR codes. For creating such codes, there should be solutions out there as well. Snapchat for example seems to use a custom flavor of QR like codes, that they had to define themselves. If you want something like that, you need to put in some work yourself before someone here can help you.

Comment: I am finding any starting point where to start customized qrcodes

Comment: What did you find in a web search for "qrcode <your favorite programming language>"? Why isn't that enough?

Comment: as i stated you earlier, i need customized QR Cpde like facebook messenger and snapchat.

P.S: We have no language barriers but i will prefer "Javascript" Or PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I build Facebook like QR code scaner, but works 10-20 times faster. In repo `iOS` demo project and `MacOS` development project.

https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/QRCodes

Answer (score 0):

To start with you could look at the specifications of a QR code:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=qrcodenet

There is an implementation by Google in both PHP and Java: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/

This is all I can do for you now, if you do not provide a specific question. I can not do the implementation for you. There are several libraries out there that you could purchase a license for and then use that as your generator, but I am guessing that is not what you want.

For more information on how to use ZXing, you can just search for the tag `zxing` on this website and browse through the questions.

Hope that helps!